# The name 'rb' does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am pretty new to c# and unity, I decided to make a test game were you can control the player, the thing is I keep getting this error: 'The name 'rb' does not exist in the current context'. I have no clue what this means, but this is what I have done.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement_controller : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float Speed = 1.0f;

    

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>() as Rigidbody2D;
        rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
    }



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.velocity = (Speed, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `private Rigidbody2D rb;` underneath `public float Speed = 1.0f;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign rb as a variable.

```
public float Speed = 1.0f;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
void Awake()
{
    rb = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>() as Rigidbody2D;
    rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have only called rb within the awake function, but you have not assigned it as a global variable.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement_controller : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float Speed = 1.0f;
    public RigidBody rb; //<====
    

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>() as Rigidbody2D;
        rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
    }
```